# How use mutable object in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to use mutable object in compose function:

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldComponent(
    name: MutableState<String>,
    nameErrorState: MutableState<Boolean>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
```

I use `MutableState` because it is field for input data.
It works good.
But I check my code with `detectAll`
And it shows me error:
Using mutable objects as state in Compose will cause your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app.
Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, cannot be observed by
Compose to trigger recomposition when they change.
See https://twitter.github.io/compose-rules/rules/#do-not-use-inherently-mutable-types-as-parameters for more information. [MutableParams]

I have read info from this link but still don't understand, how should I use it.

Comment: Whatever tool is generating that warning is wrong. `MutableState` is *specifically* the way to have mutable state in Compose. The code you've shown is fine.

Comment: You should hoist state in the parent composable and pass just the immutable value (String)+callback for the change if need be.

Comment: Just pass the value for exemple instead of `name : MutableState<String>` just pass `name : String`

Comment: The warning message is not fitting for MutableState since it will still trigger recompositions, but it's still an antipattern to pass mutable stuff around such that it can be mutated by downstream Composables (unexpectedly from the viewpoint of upstream Composables). Just like it's an antipattern to pass MutableLists around between classes in general object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the data and callback to change it:

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldComponent(
    name: String,
    nameErrorState: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNameChanged: ((String) -> Unit) = {}
)
```

This way TextFieldComponent is always redrawn when the name is changed.
You can also pass name as mutable data from outer Composable:

```
@Composable
fun Content() {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextFieldComponent(
        name,
        nameErrorState = name.isEmpty(),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
        onNameChanged = { newValue -> name = newValue})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a standard rule, you shouldn't have a mutable state as a parameter to a composable function. Because, in Kotlin arguments are immutable by design. If you wish to change the state of a variable within the composable, you can have muttable state of local variable for that.

```
@Composable 
fun Profile(initName: String) {
    var name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(initState) }

    TextFieldComponent(
        name,
        nameErrorState = name.isEmpty(),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
        onNameChanged = { newValue -> name = newValue})
    }
}
```